# How to record a video automatically in Iphone app without user interaction

Tags: iphone, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working an iphone app that needs to record a vedio automatically.

I used mobile coreservices framework and using that. I made it to came into video mode and clicking on record option its start capturing a vedio. But I want it automatically that is.. I should able to record a video without clicking on record option. That is when video mode comes up its automatically start record video.

Could any one help?

Comment: Sounds dangerous to me ;-) and most probably shouldn't be possible

Answer (score 0):

You can look at UIImagePickerControllers startVideoCapture method which is used to start taking video from the camera, this is to be used when you arent using the camera standard controlors and you provide and overlay view. Here is a reference [UIImagePickerCOntroller ref](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImagePickerController/startVideoCapture). If this is not enough for you, you might want to look into AVFoundation framework which gives you a lot more control over video capturing process...hope that helps