# Record a video automatically for 15 secs and save it to directory

Tags: iphone, ios, video

I want to record a video from my iphone device automatically when i press a button and after recording for 15 secs the video should stop and i want to save the video to the directory.

I have tried using imagepicker but for that we need to manually press start button to start video recording.  I want that when user presses a button camera should start recoding video.

Thanks.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457774/how-to-record-a-video-automatically-in-iphone-app-without-user-interaction) may help you

Comment: @RDC have tired that but not recording automatically

Comment: Have you tried "AVCaptureStillImageOutput" of AVFoundation ?

Comment: @iManan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932614/video-recording-using-avfoundation-framework-iphone i have seen this but i guess its not full code

Comment: Try this:: http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using `UIImagePickerController` itself. You mentioned that you need to press start button manually but that is not right.

Refer [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

There are instance method available for capturing video by code.`startVideoCapture` and `stopVideoCapture`.

On button's click instantiate imagePicker object.. and than call following method.

```
[yourImagePickerObject startVideoCapture];
```

After that you can either call timer or perform selector after delay of 15 dec and can call

```
[yourImagePickerObject stopVideoCapture];
```

this method will call your image picker's delegate method `– imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`

you can here handle the media and write it to document directory.

**UPDATE**

On button's click you are presenting image picker and calling the `startVideoCapture` method than even this is not working than just try following on button's event after presentModalView line:

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 1.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [yourImagePickerobj startVideoCapture];
    [objImgPicker performSelector:@selector(stopVideoCapture) withObject:nil afterDelay:15];
});
```

You can try by changing the delayInSeconds' value.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: i have tried this method before this line  [self presentModalViewController:videoRecorder animated:YES]; still its not recording automatically

Comment: Yes that worked but after video is captured i am geting an option use and retake i dont want and just want to save the video

Comment: try to set `videoRecorder.showsCameraControls=NO;` Not sure if works but you can try it.

Comment: no that dint help either. Its just not showing controls but the video is not getting stopped

Comment: This will help but there will be empty bar at bottom. You need to manage it by your own.

Comment: Have you called `stopVideoCapture` method after 15 secs? Check the updated dispatch block. This is working for me if I set showCameraControl to NO.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28237/discussion-between-kapil-choubisa-and-dhara)

Comment: I am using startVideoCapture on a button and other  stopVideoCapture , but i cant save the record video because didfinshpickingmediainfo method not working .. can any body help me??

Comment: have you set delegate for your imagepicker? `imagePicker.delegate = self;`

Comment: Sorry @Priyal , i haven't remembered it

Answer (score 1):

May be setting `VideoMaximumuration` to 15 sec will solve your problem

`[yourImagePickerObject setVideoMaximumDuration:15];`