# iOS Swift - Save video automatically using UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift3, uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture

In my current code (using Swift 3, iOS 10, Xcode 8.2.1), I am trying to record multiple videos in a loop using `UIImagePickerController`, without user interaction.

Currently I am able to start and stop video capturing using `startVideoCapture()` and `stopVideoCapture()` methods, and getting the information of video in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`. But `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is being called only after user clicks on 'Use Video' button shown on UI.

Is there anyway I can get the video data and continue recording again without having user to click on 'Use Video' option? Or is there a way to trigger `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method once `stopVideoCapture()` is being called?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out based on the discussion [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28237/discussion-between-kapil-choubisa-and-dhara) which I found from this post- [Record a video automatically for 15 secs and save it to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012561/record-a-video-automatically-for-15-secs-and-save-it-to-directory)

Basically, if you are hiding the controls, `cameraController.showsCameraControls = false` , then it will trigger `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` after you call `stopVideoCapture()`.

Though it would be interesting to know if `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` can be triggered even when camera controls are being shown.

Comment: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is not called if the camera controls are visible or not. I have set my delegate.